# Rails doesn't allow to create new enum - instance method already defined by another enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, ruby-on-rails-6

Trying to add enum to User class:

```
enum vehicle: { car: 1, bus: 2, other: 3 }, _prefix: true
```

and rails throws an error

> You tried to define an enum named "vehicle" on the model "Spree::User", but this will generate an instance method "vehicle_car?", which is already defined by another enum.

I had tried with another name, suffix and prefix options, and made `ack` in gems folder. I suppose that can be Zeitwerk problem but I don't have idea how to fix that.

Working on `Rails version: 6`

Comment: where do your create this enum? Is it possible that part of code that contains enum can be called more than once?

Comment: in model decorator

Comment: You need to show more of your code, or people are just forced to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a custom prefix/suffix to make it differ from `vehicle_car?`

```
enum vehicle: { car: 1, bus: 2, other: 3 }, _prefix: :vehicle_type


model_instance.vehicle_type_car!
model_instance.vehicle_type_car? # => false
```

For reference

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: I had tried different suffixes and prefixes, also as I mentioned in post different names of enum also gives me same error

Comment: Can you add the model file in the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `validates` call referencing the enum, make sure you are typing the plural form, `vehicles.keys`, not `vehicle.keys`, otherwise you will get this error.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum vehicle: { car: 1, bus: 2, other: 3 }
  validates :vehicle, inclusion: { in: vehicles.keys }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today. I debugged it and tried to troubleshoot and it turned out it was something that had nothing to do with the `enum` method but rather some syntax problem I've had. One of the validations I had in place was missing the initial parameter:

```rb
class DocumentTemplate < ApplicationRecord

  enum status: [
    :published,
    :disabled,
    :draft
  ], _suffix: true

  enum trigger_type: {
    auto: 'auto',
    manual: 'manual'
  }, _suffix: true

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { maximum: 250 }
  validates :description, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :status, presence: true
  validates :trigger_source, if: :auto_trigger_type? # here lies the problem

end
```

Look how the last line with the validation was missing the actual type of validation I wanted to do to `trigger_source` attribute so that is clearly something I missed but instead of getting that error I was getting this:

```
`raise_conflict_error': You tried to define an enum named "status" on the model "DocumentTemplate", but this will generate a instance method "published_status?", which is already defined by another enum. (ArgumentError)
```

Notice how the raised error says I was trying to define an `enum` within `DocumentTemplate` that was already defined. To add to the confusion I do have some `status` enums elsewhere in some other models with similar values so I thought that was the issue. So I went to one of those other files that had the same `status` enum and commented it out. Result? Same error, so that's when I noticed something fishy was going on...

I moved the validations to be first and then the enums like so:

```rb
class DocumentTemplate < ApplicationRecord

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { maximum: 250 }
  validates :description, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :status, presence: true
  validates :trigger_source, if: :auto_trigger_type? # here lies the problem

  enum status: [
    :published,
    :disabled,
    :draft
  ], _suffix: true

  enum trigger_type: {
    auto: 'auto',
    manual: 'manual'
  }, _suffix: true

end
```

And then I've got a different error:

```
`validates': You need to supply at least one validation (ArgumentError)
```

That's when I re-reviewed the validations and noticed that I was missing the `presence: true` in the `trigger_source` validation.

So long story short, the way the ruby parses the file seems to be involved here. Check the code BEFORE your enum declarations, you may have a syntax error.

Hope this helps someone else, this took me a while to figure out :/

Answer (score -1):

That could happen if you have a method or column called `vehicle_car`, because enum method will try to create a helper for you with that name. Is that the case?

Comment: As I mentioned in post different names of enum also gives me same error, also I made `ack` project directory and gems directory, it wan't find anything with that name.